# PHP problem sets for beginners

Tags: php, language-agnostic

There are plenty of tutorials and step by step guides out there on the internet, but they give mostly examples which you can run in the computer.

Is there a good separate set of problems that beginners can try to solve themselves. If existing solutions are available, even better.

**Update**
To put it more clearly, is there any resource online with a collection of Practice Questions which beginners can refer to? A set of problems in using operators, using arrays, etc?

Comment: Could you please refine what you are looking for? Do you mean something like http://projecteuler.net? What is meant by *separate set of problems* and what is the issue with *guides […] that have to be run in a computer*. I mean, isnt that what programming languages are for?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at these sets http://codingkata.org/ . They're language independent and cover some important beginner fields: arrays, string operations, recursion, regular expressions, etc.

I wouldn't recommend Project Euler as it has more to do with math and advanced programming and it won't help you develop too many useful skills.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this doesn't come across as spam but I'm actually working on a project right now that is going to allow people to upload their own projects so that people like yourself can browse through real life example of peoples work. - [booyahachieved.com](http://booyahachieved.com/projects/view/booyahachieved-com)

I do need people to contribute code first though! and please remember it's still in development!